# How to declare a positional parameter of a function as a global variable in python?

Tags: python

How to declare the positional parameter `var` in the following function as a global variable?

```py
v1 = 'a1'
v2 = 'a2'
# and there may be other variables like v3, v4

def test(var):
    global var
    var += '-new'


test(v1)
print(v1)  # I hope this can be a1-new

test(v2)
print(v2)  # I hope this can be a2-new
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do this. Just pass in parameters and return results. If you find yourself typing `global`, stop and rethink your design. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's a great suggestion!Thanks.

Comment: When you call `test(v1)` python calls test with the value from `v1`. The called function has no idea that the object `'a1'` came from the global variable `v1`. If you really wanted to change the global variable by name, you'd have to pass in its name, `v1`.  Would `test("v1")` be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: You'll need to compare any solutions to just doing `v1 = test(v1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use global variables, but if you do, do a for loop like so:

```
var_names = ["v1", "v2"]
for i in var_names:
    globals()[i] = f"{i}-new"
```

To access your new global variables, just type: `globals()["var_name"]`